# drop down list within JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I wnt that when i enter some letter in the textfield then the related items should be picked up from my database and should appear as a drop down list.
For Example:
I typed 'J' in text Field, in my database is having names such as {"Juby','Jaz','Jasmine','Joggy'....}
Theses names should appear as a list. So that i could select one from them.and so on for other leters as well.
Is there any predefined control in awt??
Thnx

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use a JComboBox?  By default, when the user types a keystroke in a read-only combobox and an item in the combobox starts with the typed keystroke, the combobox will select that item.

Or you could set the JComboBox to be editable using `setEditable(true)`, and use a [KeySelectionManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.KeySelectionManager.html).  The link explains selecting an item in a JComboBox component with multiple keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

This is a small example implementing what ( i think) you asked for.. the database in this example is a vector of strings.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Answer extends JFrame {
    public static final int MAXITEMS = 100;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    String[] myDataBase = { "Juby", "Jaz", "Jasmine", "Joggy", "one", "dog","cat", "parot" };
    String[] listItems;
    JList theList = new JList();

    public Answer() {
        this.add(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        panel.add(textField);
        panel.add(theList);

        textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
                String compareString = ("" + textField.getText() + ke.getKeyChar());
                listItems = new String[MAXITEMS];

                if (compareString.trim().length() > 0 ){
                    int counter = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < myDataBase.length; i++) {
                        if (counter < MAXITEMS) {
                            if (myDataBase[i].length() >= compareString.length() &&
                                    myDataBase[i].substring(0, compareString.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(compareString)) {
                                listItems[counter] = myDataBase[i];
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                theList.setListData(listItems);
            }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Answer answer = new Answer();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                answer.pack();
                answer.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Mind that a lower case letter is different from an upper one, meaning that in order to see the words "Juby","Jaz","Jasmine" you should use "J" and not j.
I copy pasted the code and it works allright. Do you have an error message.. and if you do what exactly does it say?

Comment: @Kais fixed the exception occured when the input length was more than 3 letters.
The code worked, but it was case sensitive, so typing a "j" will return no results. 
I changed the code to be case insensitive to avoid future misunderstandings

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [GlazedLists](http://www.publicobject.com/glazedlists/), as it has some support for [auto-completion](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/glazedlists-1.8.0/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/swing/AutoCompleteSupport.html).